# Intent between activities

Tags: android, android-intent, react-native

I have a React Native application. There is the MainActivity which is generated by the React Native, and I created a PluginActivity. The plugin activity handle a request from an other application. The plugin activity doing the following: Getting a file, save it and through the shared prefs it is intent to the react native MainActivity.

**The problem:**
The intent part of the application is not working. I create the Intent as the follow:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(PluginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
long valid = validTo - System.currentTimeMillis();
String uriString = "company://upload";
intent.setData(Uri.parse(uriString));
startActivity(intent);
```

I would like to catch the uriString in the React Native with Linking, but not working. 
There is the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.company"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="company"
                android:host="*" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />

      <activity android:name=".PluginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

When I'm trying the deep-linking with the following it is working properly:

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "company://$1" com.company/.MainActivity
```

The PluginActivity also working because the following text written to the display.

```
Toast.makeText(PluginActivity.this, "Upload started, starting useer autorization", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Versions:

- react-native: "0.42.0"
- Android SDK: 23

Comment: you are specifying the component (in this case MainActivity.class) to open. Can you try removing that and then try the same. Use Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW) instead of first line.

Comment: It is not a web domain, it is another activity.

Comment: That seems working. Hm, thank you, I used it: `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uriString))`, please write the answer.

Comment: glad it worked :) I have added the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are specifying the component (in this case MainActivity.class) to open. Can you try removing the specific component name and then try the same. Use the following:

```
long valid = validTo - System.currentTimeMillis();
String uriString = "company://upload";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uriString));
startActivity(intent);
```

Documentation of [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(java.lang.String,%20android.net.Uri)) Construct.